# Emacs: Down arrow key skips lines when window too short

Tags: emacs, cursor, skip

When I use Emacs in full screen mode, the Down arrow key works just fine for navigating down a source code buffer. But when the window gets too short (e.g., C-x 2), then pressing Down begins to skip "paragraphs" of code, making it hard to edit the desired line.

This behavior occurs for the Down arrow key, `C-n`, and `M-x next-line`, as well as for the reverse functions Up, `C-l`, and `M-x previous-line`.

Can someone help me modify my `~/.emacs` to prevent these line skips from happening?

I'm using Homebrew Emacs 24.2.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.2.

**Update**: This behavior also occurs in Emacs for Mac OS X, 24.3.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to customize (`M-x customize-variable RET`) variable `line-move-visual` to be `t`.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
(setq scroll-conservatively 1)
```

This also seems to have a similar effect.  I'm unclear on how exactly they differ.

```
(setq scroll-step 1)
```